# Go type inference and named return variables

Tags: go

In Go if you give a name to the return variables they are initialised to their zero values when the function begins. I'm using this feature below with the `err` variable on the line `usr, err = user.Current()`. Is it possible to use type inference for `usr` variable and not for the `err` variable? I don't really want to declare `var usr *user.user` I would much rather use type inference here.

```
func getConfigFilepath(userSuppliedFilepath string) (filepath string, err error) {

    if userSuppliedFilepath == "" {
        usr, err = user.Current()
        filepath = path.Join(usr.HomeDir, ".myprogram.config.json")
    }

    return
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do what you want to do.

Your choices are to not use named returns, or like you said declare

```
var usr *user.User 
usr, err = user.Current()
```

In some circumstances you could do that, but in your case you are are creating a new `err` because you are within the if block and it is making a locally scoped reference to a new `err`.

Comment: Ah ok. That is what I thought.

Comment: why not just use the shorthand `:=`?

Answer (score 1):

You can if you slightly restructure your code and you don't put the `user.Current()` call in another block (`if` in your case), then you can do it with the `:=` [Short variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations):

```
func getConfigFilepath(userSuppliedFilepath string) (filepath string, err error) {
    if userSuppliedFilepath != "" {
        return userSuppliedFilepath, nil
    }

    usr, err := user.Current()
    filepath = path.Join(usr.HomeDir, ".myprogram.config.json")
    return
}
```

**Edit:**

You might say this code is longer than your original, but note that your original code is *not yet valid* and is also *incomplete* because it does not handle the case when `userSuppliedFilepath` is provided. You should compare the proposed code to the full and valid version of your code which is below:

```
func getConfigFilepath(userSuppliedFilepath string) (filepath string, err error) {
    if userSuppliedFilepath == "" {
        var usr *user.User
        usr, err = user.Current()
        filepath = path.Join(usr.HomeDir, ".myprogram.config.json")
    } else {
        filepath = userSuppliedFilepath
    }

    return
}
```

And now the proposed code isn't longer (on the contrary, it's a little shorter).

Comment: Oh yeah, I can use type inference if I'm in the top level scope. But I think when I now read the function it isn't as clear and is more lines of code. https://play.golang.org/p/0LY2V1fhjP

Comment: @Neil Please see my edited answer. You were comparing the proposed code to an invalid and incomplete version of your code. Completing yours and modifying your proposed edit of the code changes the picture. But which one is more readable is not an objective question. But your original question was whether you can use type inference is solved with this code: this code doesn't include the type `*user.User`.